# Issues with DateTime.Now C# When adding records to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having a strange issue with my project. I have an upload excel file that automatically updates a table. The upload part is irrelevant, just adding it for clarity. When using this I call the dateTime as `CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now`. It does not get this from the excel file. I get a Out of range error - dateTime2 to dateTime conversion. The table has a `dateTime` for the column. I am scratching my head because I have the same exact code in another controller for another table and it works fine. Tables where created at the same time in SQL. So the code and the tables are exact. One gives the error and the other does not. Date comes back fine with a Breakpoint. Is there something in the code below that you can see that would be causing this?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
    {
        GeneralEntities objEntity = new GeneralEntities();
        string data = "";
        if (FileUpload != null)
        {
            if (FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                string filename = FileUpload.FileName;
                if (filename.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    string targetpath = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/DetailFormatInExcel/");
                    FileUpload.SaveAs(targetpath + filename);
                    string pathToExcelFile = targetpath + filename;
                    string sheetName = "Sheet1";
                    var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathToExcelFile);
                    var Equipment = from a in excelFile.Worksheet<AirFloatTablesExcelModel>(sheetName) select a;

                    foreach (var a in Equipment)
                    {
                        var ishaveModel = db.EquipmentModels.Where(d => d.Title == a.EquipmentModel).FirstOrDefault();
                        
                        
                        AirFloatTables at = new AirFloatTables
                        {
                            AirFloatTableId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            EquipmentModelId = ishaveModel.EquipmentModelId,
                            Size = a.Size,
                            Type = a.Type,
                            TiltHeight = a.TiltHeight,
                            DWGRef = a.DWGRef,
                            Price = a.Price,
                            SortOrder = a.SortOrder,
                            CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                            CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now
                        };
                        db.AirFloatTables.Add(at);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    data = "This file is not valid format";
                    TempData["Message"] = data;
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                data = "Only Excel file format is allowed";
                TempData["Message"] = data;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (FileUpload == null)
            {
                data = "Please choose Excel file";
            }
            TempData["Message"] = data;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

[image: Data table]

UPDATE:
It might be worth it to say that I took the created date out of my code and then in SQL for the column I put `GetDATE()`. The issue is still there So It is not happening on the `CreatedDate`. If by chance the `UpdatedDate` is the issue I do not know why that would be. When debugging I do see that `UpdatedDate` does come back with zero's However my code does not call for an insertion of `UpdatedDate` So why would it try to insert it anyway? Or is it just a code thing where it sees it and flags that it is not correct. If this is the case, then why does the code in my other controller, that is exactly the same, not do the same thing?

Comment: Is this code using Entity Framework? If so, which version? Code first, or using an .edmx file?

Comment: code first .net 4.6.1 just database no file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not store a value for `UpdatedDate`, which is nullable, true, but this error happens mostly when for any reason a DateTime of year, month, day, etc. having a value of 0 is attempted to be inserted/updated as a value.

Comment: Or in other words: the property on the C# class is not nullable, and therefore returning `01-01-0001` which is out of range

Comment: I am not inserting a UpdatedDate. That is why it is nullable. That only gets inserted when the record is updated not when it is created. As I have duplicate code for another table that works. Same scenario just different table. And the table in SQL is exactly the same as far as dates go.. Also Date is coming back not zero's.

Comment: @ScottPurtan As Charlieface said, you have to make the `UpdatedDate` property in your `AirFloatTables` class nullable. Like so: `public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }`

Comment: @nadz Yes I just realized that. I looked in my model, and noticed I forgot the ?. Unbelievable! It is the small stupid things that kill you the most. I made about 10 models, views, and controllers in a row. Basically all the same just different tables. I did it in the first one, that works. Now i need to back through all of them to make sure that was done. To many late nights I guess...

Comment: In other words I didn't even check that because it is a no brainer to do and have done it a million times...